# How to change caret and newline rendering behavior of Gtk3 TextView?

Tags: gtk3

For example, I want to render caret in underline style (like some console), instead of thin vertical bar. And show a particular char at where there is a "newline" (like some editors do). How can I reach that goal? Is overriding its methods the only way?

Comment: Could you explain what your goal is? Maybe there is a better Gtk Widget for your purpose than a Gtk TextView.

Comment: @theGtknerd Hi, I am trying to simulate the interface of old console (green/black, block caret) to make a simple old style game. The newline thing is more like, how do I interfere with the text that is shown.

Comment: One possibility would be a [VteTerminal](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/VTE), depending on your app.

Comment: @theGtknerd VTE does not simply expose the "text content".